# Website layout falls apart in Firefox Browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating and editing a custom Wordpress theme and for some reason the entire homepage falls apart in Firefox. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

The site looks fine so far in other browsers:

http://testwebdesign.com/

Comment: damn bro, that sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to the content wrap:

```
#contentWrap {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```